# How does a method wait until an anonymous delegate completes?

Tags: c#, events, anonymous-methods, anonymous-delegates

I have the following snippet of code (as an example) that looks up a contact:

```
public string Search()
{
    string address = "";

    ContactManager manager = new ContactManager();

    // LookupComplete is just a plain event
    manager.LookupComplete += delegate
    {
        address = manager.Address;
    };

    manager.SearchFor("bob");
    return address; // Address always appears to be populated
}
```

**Update:**
Here's the ContactManager:

```
public class ContactManager
{
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public event LookupComplete;

    public void SearchFor(string query)
    {
        SomeParser parser = new Parser();
        parser.TokenParsed += new EventHandler<TokenParseEventArgs>(tokenParsed);
        parser.Parse(query);    
    }

    private void tokenParsed(object sender,TokenParseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Message == "EOF")
        {
            Address = e.Message.Address;

            if (LookupComplete != null)
                LookupComplete(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }   
    }   
}
```

The `Search` method doesn't return until that event is fired (a behaviour I didn't realise was standard for anonymous methods/delegates).

I'm confused however how the code generated for the anonymous delegate signals the `Search` method when it's complete.

I've tried putting a Sleep(5000) in the ContactManager.Address property as I thought it may have been from the ContactManager simply returning very quickly, but that makes no difference.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whether the delegate was created with an anonymous method. It's just that `manager.SearchFor` is apparently a synchronous method, which doesn't return until the lookup has finished. That makes it slightly strange for it to have an event for "lookup complete", admittedly... it looks like you could simplify your method to simply:

```
public string Search()
{
    ContactManager manager = new ContactManager();
    manager.SearchFor("bob");
    return manager.Address;
}
```

Now it's possible that there's *also* an asynchronous option available on `ContactManager` - it's hard to say without knowing more about the class. If there *is* an asynchronous option, you should consider what behaviour you actually want... are you happy with `Search` being synchronous, or do you actually want it to complete immediately and take some action when the search has finished?

Comment: I tried to simplify it with contacts, the 'ContactManager' is actually this: http://hg.shrinkrays.net/spruce/src/0e9aee07563e/Spruce.Core/Search/SearchParser.cs. It parses tokens in a query, but doesn't run synchronously as far as I'm aware

Comment: @Chris S: I can't see anything in that code suggesting it's asynchronous... but I can't see the code for LALRParser. Is there some documentation which is suggesting to you that it really *is* asynchronous?

Comment: @Chris S I didn't find any asynchronous calls there

Comment: @Jon and @gor The SearchFor completes, the TokenParsed event fires later unless I've missed something?

Comment: @Chris S: But what makes you think that? Do you have any evidence that SearchFor completes *before* the TokenParsed event is raised?

Comment: @Jon I thought/assumed the .NET runtime would complete the SearchFor method call before the event, even if it's microseconds slower

Comment: @Jon I've +1 the comment that made it clear for me - another gap in my knowledge plugged (I assumed events are run separately from the main method stack somehow)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on implementation of `ContactManager` class. If it is sinle threaded and synchronous it cannot return earlier, then work is done.